# How to make paging menu with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, servlets

I'm developing classified website.In ad view page i have to get ads data from db. So i used servlet to do it. all work is done now and work perfectly. But after all it's look soo basic(I mean not attractive.). I want to make it look professional. How i am doin this? please help me to look this professional.
Thank You.
Dilshan.

Servlet code is this :

```
    int page = 1;
    int recordsPerPage = 5;
    if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
    page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
    //  EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
    View_ads_cls be=new View_ads_cls();
    List<Ads_view_to> list = be.getRecentAdd((page-1)*recordsPerPage,
    recordsPerPage);
    int noOfRecords = be.getNoOfRecords();
    int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
    request.setAttribute("allads", list);
    request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
    request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("ad_viewer.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

jsp page is here: 
        
        
        Emp ID
        Emp Name
        Salary
        Dept Name
        Dept Name2

```
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${allads}">
    <tr>
    <td>${employee.brand}</td>
    <td>${employee.description}</td>
    <td>${employee.price}</td>
     <td><img src=${employee.imageurl}></td>


 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
<c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
<td><a href="view_ads?page=${currentPage - 1}">Previous</a></td>
</c:if>

<%--For displaying Page numbers.
The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
<td>${i}</td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
 <td><a href="view_ads?page=${i}">${i}</a></td>
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
</table>

<%--For displaying Next link --%>
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
<td><a href="view_ads?page=${currentPage + 1}">Next</a></td>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Is it the actual visual appearance in the browser that you are concerned with or the code?

Comment: Yes. this code working correctly. I want to make it look professionally design in browser.

Comment: You need to look into css, or check out twitter bootstrap to use as a framework

Comment: any good examples how to it with css?

Comment: It really depends on what you want and how you want it to look, that I can not assist you with

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following links
[link1](http://woork.blogspot.in/2008/03/perfect-pagination-style-using-css.html),
[Link2](http://www.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/beautiful-pagination/),
[Link3](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/).
You must spend time with search engines to find out the pagination which suits for you.